# How to add a pause between lines in a multi-line paste into Telnet terminal on Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, telnet

I am using the `telnet` command on a Bash terminal in Linux to connect to a Console of a firmware running on an embedded system. The FW is controlled via console commands. To make things easier, I scripted the commands in a text editor and from there, I cut-and-paste the lines.

To save time, I am trying to paste several sequential commands in a single multiline paste. The problem is that the firmware's command line processing is slower than the paste speed, and parts of the second or third commands in the sequence are getting lost.

On a different setup I used TeraTerm to do the same. There, one can configure a pause between lines in the multiline paste.

Is there a way to achieve the same using the `telnet` Bash command?

Alternatively, is there a way to get Bash itself to add the required pause between lines when pasting in the Telnet prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Try writing a bash script that prints the telnet commands with the `sleep` command in between. And pipe the bash script to your telnet shell.

commands.sh

```
echo 'command 1'
sleep 1
echo 'command 2'
sleep 1
...
```

```
$ bash commands.sh | telnet
```

Comment: Thanks. anything that is "script based" will not help in this case, b/c I am not running a linear script but rather multiple, nonlinear tests not in a particular order.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to avoid pasting entirely and to start using `expect` for CLI automation. While it can do timed delays, one of its main features is being able to wait for a *specific reply,* such as an `+OK` or `>` response, before continuing with the next command.

For example, if the device responds with a `>` prompt before you can continue (it can be partial, the same example below will match a prompt like `Router>` as well), you could have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set host [lindex $argv 0]

spawn "telnet" $host
expect "Username:" { send "admin\n" }
expect "Password:" { send "hunter2\n" }
expect ">" { send "do_something\n" }
expect ">" { send "do_something_else\n" }
expect {
    "FAILED:" { send "do_it_differently\n"; exp_continue }
    ">"       { send "do_third_thing\n" }
}
```

Expect scripts are based on Tcl, so if you wanted to add e.g. command-line options for different modes, use Tcl language reference (`foreach` and `switch`). Another similar tool is Pexpect, which does the same but in Python.

> Alternatively, is there a way to get Bash itself to add the required pause between lines when pasting in the Telnet prompt?

Pasting in the Telnet prompt does not go through Bash. The terminal is talking directly to Telnet while the only thing Bash is doing is sitting there waiting for /usr/bin/telnet to exit.

If not Telnet itself, then your terminal app (e.g. xterm or PuTTY) would be the one responsible for adding such delays – just like the option you had in TeraTerm.

Comment: Thanks. anything that is "script based" will not help in this case, b/c I am not running a linear script but rather multiple, nonlinear tests not in a particular order.

Comment: Yes, I imagine it is telnet that should add the pauses, which is why I asked about this.

Comment: Any recommendation on a simple terminal emulator (TeraTerm or PuTTY style) for Linux?